# Lift a function to a Conduit Sink

Tags: haskell, yesod, conduit

I have a function `f :: ByteString -> String`, and need a `Sink ByteString (ResourceT IO)`. 
How do I get this?

Unfortunately, the docs were not very helpful...

Comment: What do you want the sink to do?

Comment: And `Sink ByteString (ResourceT IO)` isn't a type. Do you mean `Sink ByteString (ResourceT IO) String`?

Comment: Yes, sorry.`Sink ByteString (ResourceT IO) String` was needed. The sink was supposed to take the result of fileSource in a Yesod file upload, and compute its md5 hash (using `Yesod.Static.base64md5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need anything to do with resourceT in this conduit.

In order to return it all in one big string composed from all the little bytestrings, you'll have to accumulate pieces for awhile, then return it a the end.

```
fSink :: Monad m => Sink ByteString m String
fSink = go []
  where
    go accum = do
      x <- await
      case x of
        Nothing -> return . f . B.concat . reverse $ accum
        Just x' -> go (x':accum)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The requirement for ResourceT is just due to the way Yesod handles file uploads since version 1.1.
      
You get a `Source (ResourceT IO) ByteString` instead of a `ByteString` as it was in Yesod 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general solution to the problem: let's take any function `i -> r`, where `i` is a `Monoid`, and turn it into a sink by folding all of the `await`s up with `mappend`.

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List as CL
import Data.Monoid

monoidFold :: (Monoid i, Monad m) => (i -> r) -> Sink i m r
monoidFold f = f `fmap` CL.fold mappend mempty
```

Since `ByteString` is a `Monoid`, your function of type `ByteString -> String` can be used as the argument of `monoidFold`.

```
myMD5 :: ByteString -> String
monoidFold myMD5 :: Monad m => Sink ByteString m String
```